# CSS columns aren't aligning up

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

So I've been racking my brains over this CSS for a while now, need someone to look over it with a fresh set of eyes... Basically what's happening is that I have 4 columns which sit next to each other in the Footer, but the last column is automatically shifting underneath the 3rd column. I can't see what's happening to make it do that?!

Check out the link below:

[test.snowflakesoftware.com](http://test.snowflakesoftware.com/)

Below is the CSS:

```
    #mod_footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/footer.jpg);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #212530;
}
    .mod_footer_container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1200px;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
        .mod_footer_col {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            padding-right: 25px;
        }
        #mod_footer_col_end {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
        }
            #nav-bottom-left,
            #nav-bottom-left ul {list-style-image: url(images/bullet.png); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #FFF;}
            #nav-bottom-left a {}
            #nav-bottom-left li {margin-left: 25px;}

            #nav-bottom-right,
            #nav-bottom-right ul {list-style-image: url(images/bullet.png); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #FFF;}
            #nav-bottom-right a {}
            #nav-bottom-right li {}

            p.footer_title {color: #9bcbf3;}
            p.footer {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; color: #FFF;}
            p.footer .menu-item {list-style-image: url(http://www.snowflakesoftware.com/wp-content/themes/images/bullet.png);}

    .mod_footer_container_bottom {
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1200px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
        #mod_footer_bottom_col {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

And below is the HTML:

```
<div id="mod_footer"><footer>

    <div class="mod_footer_container">

        <div class="mod_footer_col">
        <p class="footer_title">Quick Links</p>
        <br />
            <div id="nav-bottom-left" class="nav"><nav>
                <p class="footer"><?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'footer-menu-one' )); /* editable within the Wordpress backend */ ?></p>
            </nav></div><!--#nav-bottom-left-->
        </div><!--mod_footer_col-->

        <div class="mod_footer_col">
        <p class="footer_title">In our Labs</p>
        <br />
            <div id="nav-bottom-right" class="nav"><nav>
                <p class="footer"><?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'footer-menu-two' )); /* editable within the Wordpress backend */ ?></p>
            </nav></div><!--#nav-bottom-right-->
        </div><!--mod_footer_col-->

        <div class="mod_footer_col">
        <p class="footer_title">Become a Partner</p>
        <br />
        <p class="footer">We're always looking for new partners to team up with in order to encourage and facilitate the use of geospatial data and components within mainstream IT systems. Want to join us? All you need to do is contact us and we can get the ball rolling...</p>
        <br />
        <p class="footer">Join our Partner Programme</p>
        </div><!--mod_footer_col-->

        <div id="mod_footer_col_end">
        <p class="footer">Interoperable data exchange via open standards - It's what we're all about.</p>
        <br />
        <p class="footer">Whether you want to load OS MasterMap, publish INSPIRE compliant data or know how to deliver AIXM via web services or any other GML data, we can help. Our software is enabling geographic information specialists around the world to easily load, publish, visualise and share geospatial data....</p>
        </div><!--mod_footer_col_end-->

    </div><!--mod_footer_container-->

    <div class="mod_footer_container_bottom">

    <div id="mod_footer_bottom_col">
        <p class="footer">&copy; <?php echo date("Y") ?> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>. <?php _e('All Rights Reserved.'); ?></p>
    </div><!--mod_footer_bottom_col-->

    </div><!--mod_footer_container_bottom-->

</footer></div><!--mod_footer-->
```

As you can see by visiting the link, the 4th column starts with the words 'Interoperable data exchange via open standards'

Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: works for me ;) firefox 16.0.1

Comment: As a little extra thing as I believe SpaceBeers answered the question, your viewport is wrong: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1"/> - the ";" is not allowed. Should be a comma.

Comment: In Chrome, changing the width to `20%` on each of the elemtns lets them fit. For some reason, I think the `25%` seems to refer to the entire width of the screen, as supposed to the parent element?

Answer (score 5):

Your cols are all 25% width. So 4 of them should make up 100% of the width of the footer.

Where you've gone wrong is adding the padding of 25px to them. So your essentially saying 100% + 75px which is forcing your last col to do what it's doing.

Either do your measurements in pixels as you know the width of the footer and subtract the 25px padding from the width or do it all in percentages but make sure the width + padding isn't > 100%.

Comment: Just realized... Always the way when you're staring at something for ages, clouds the vision and etc. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. Remember there is no > 100% and you're laughing. Please accept the answer if it's helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Spacebeer's answer, here is an alternative solution to the problem:

css3 box-sizing: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Using this as

```
.mod_footer_col{box-sizing:border-box;}
```

would allow you to keep the padding.

Note: this doesn't work in ancient browsers. (ie7)

Comment: Thanks. I like how IE7 is considered ancient now. It's a shame this isn't widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-right:25px` from `.mod_footer_col` as your columns have width `25%` each. And this `25px` padding when added in `25%` columns width it pushes your 4<sup>th</sup> column down.

You can add padding in `p.footer` to keep spacing between columns paragraphs.

Comment: What about everything apart from <p> tags?